# Discord.py trouble with getting author pings

Tags: python, discord.py

Hi I am trying to make a discord bot and trying to make a command that pings people whenever they type `$$hello` but there seems to be an issue with the parameters which I cannot figure out here is the code:

```
@client.command(name = "hello")
async def hello(ctx,message):

    await event.msg.reply('Hello {}'.format(event.author.mention))
```

I have been looking for an answer and it's probably something really stupid that i'm doing wrong but any help is greatly appreciated thanks

Answer (score 1):

What is `event`?  You should be using `ctx`, which is the [invocation context](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#invocation-context) of the command

```
await ctx.send('Hello {}'.format(ctx.author.mention))
```

Answer (score 0):

It should look like this:

```py
@client.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'Hello {ctx.author.mention}')
```

That's how it would look in rewrite version of discord.py